# Adding specific index to SQL Server table to improve performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, indexing

I have a slow query on a table.

```
SELECT (some columns)
FROM Table
```

This table has an `ID` (integer, identity (1,1)) primary index which is the only index on this table.

The query has a `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE Field05 <> 1 
  AND (Field01 LIKE '%something%' OR Field02 LIKE '%something%' OR 
       Field03 LIKE'%something%' OR Field04 LIKE'%something%')
```

- `Field05` is `bit, not null`
- `Field01` is `NVarchar(255)`
- `Field02` is `NVarchar(255)`
- `Field03` is `Nchar(11)`
- `Field04` is `Varchar(50)`

The execution plan shows a "Clustered index scan" resulting in a slow execution.

I tried adding indexes:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Aziende_RagSoc ON dbo.Aziende (Field01);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Aziende_Nome ON dbo.Aziende (Field02);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Aziende_PIVA ON dbo.Aziende (Field03);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Aziende_CodFisc ON dbo.Aziende (Field04);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Aziende_Eliminata ON dbo.Aziende (Field05);
```

Same performances, and again, the execution plan shows a "Clustered index scan"
I removed these 5 indexes and added only ONE index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Aziende_Ricerca
ON Aziende (Field05)
INCLUDE (Field01, Field02, Field03, Field04)
```

Same performances, but in this situation the execution plan changes.

Is more complex but always slow.

I removed this index and added a different index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Aziende_Ricerca
ON Aziende (Field05,Field01,Field02,Field03,Field04)
```

Same performances, in this situation the execution plan remains like in the previous situation.

The execution is always slow.

I have no other ideas ... someone can help?

Comment: Using `LIKE '%something%'` with a leading `%` makes indexes on these columns useless - SQL Server will **never** be able to use any index on such a comparison.

Comment: Intersting ... and very bad new ...

Comment: You can try `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Aziende_Ricerca
ON Aziende (Field05,Field01,Field02,Field03,Field04) INCLUDE (some columns) WHERE Field05 <> 1`, but there is really not much here to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

First, you should use `Field05 = 0` rather than `Field05 <> 1`.  Equality is both easier to read and better for the optimizer.  It won't make a difference in this particular case, unless you have a clustered index starting with `Field05` or if almost all values are `1` (that is, the `0` is highly selective).

Second, in general, you can only optimize string pattern matching using a full text index.  This in turn has other limitations, such as looking for words or prefixes (but not starting with wildcards).

The one exception is if "something" is a constant.  In that case, you could add persisted computed columns with indexes to capture whether the value is present in these columns.  However, I'm guessing that "something" is not constant.

That leaves you with full text indexes or with reconsidering your data model.  Perhaps you are storing things in strings -- like lists of tags -- that should really be in a separate table.

Comment: "Something" changes at every execution. But "something" usually is only a part of one of the four fields, thus I must use LIKE '%something%', and if full-text Indexes don't want wildcards ...

Answer (score 0):

Just to chime in with a few comments.
SQL Server tends to Table Scan Even if an index is present unless it thinks the Searched field Has a Cardinality of less than 1%. With this in mind there is never going to be any value in a index on a Bit field. (cardinality 50%!)

One option you might consider is to create a Filtered Index (WHERE Field05 = 0) Then you can include your other fields in this index. 
Note this will only help you if you are not selecting any other columns from the table.

Can you check what proportion of your data has Field5=0 ?- If this is small (eg under 10%) then a filtered index might help.

I can't see any way that you can avoid a scan of some sort though - The best you can get is probably an Index scan.

Another option (essentially the same thing!) is to create a schema bound indexed view with all the columns you need and with the field5=0 filter hardcoded into the view.

Again - Unless you are certain that the Selected Column list is going to be a tiny proportion of the columns in the table then SQL will probably be faster with a table scan.  If you were only ever selecting a handful of columns from a a very wide table then an index covering these columns might help as even though it will still be a scan - there will be more rows per page than scanning the full table.

So in summary - If you can guarantee a small subset of the table cols will be selected 
AND field5 = 0 represents a minority of your rows in the table then a filtered index with Includes can be of value.

EG

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix ON dbo.Aziende(ID) INCLUDE (Field01,Field02,Field03,Field04, [other cols used by select]) WHERE (field5=0)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of fight I forgot the idea of adding an index.
Nothing changes with index.

I changed the C# code that builds the query, and now I try to understand the meaning of the "something" parameter received from the function.
If it is of type 1, then I build a WHERE on Field01
If it is of type 2, then I build a WHERE on Field02
If it is of type 3, then I build a WHERE on Field03
If it is of type 4, then I build a WHERE on Field04

This way, execution times becomes 1/4 of before.
Curstomers are satisfied.